# $x$ in intersection of maximal ideals implies $1-x$ is a unit

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, we define $J:=\bigcap_{\mathcal M \space \text{maximal}}\mathcal M$. Let $x \in J$, prove the following

- $(1-x) \in \mathcal U(R)$
- If $x^2=x$ then $x=0$

  For the second, assuming the first item is true, then there is $r \in R \setminus \{0\}$: $(1-x)r=1 \implies (x-1)(-r)=1 \implies (x-1) \in \mathcal U(R)$. So $$x^2=x \space \text{iff}$$$$x^2-x=0 \space \text{iff}$$$$x(x-1)=0$$
  Multiplying both sides by $(-r)$ yields $x=0$.

I am having problems proving the first proposition, I would appreciate hints for that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $1-x$ is not invertible, then $(1-x)$, the ideal generated by $1-x$, is strictly contained in $R$ (why?) and therefore it is contained in a maximal ideal (why?).

Comment: Thanks, I've figured out the first "why?", if $\langle 1-x \rangle=R$, then $(1-x)a=a(1-x)=1$ which is absurd. I am thinking why your second affirmation holds.

Comment: @user156441 Or you can take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull's_theorem

Comment: As for the second, if $\langle 1-x \rangle$ is not contained in any maximal ideal, then $\langle 1-x \rangle + M=R$ for any maximal ideal $M$. I don't see how I can arrive to a contradiction.

Comment: Oh, I'll read your link.

Comment: @user156441 In fact, every ideal $\ne R$ is contained in a maximal ideal; see [here](http://www.math.wustl.edu/~russw/s09.math430/zorn.pdf), Theorem 7.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that $1-x$ is not a unit, then the ideal $I=(1-x) \subsetneq R$. But then there must be a maximal ideal $M$ with $I \subseteq M$. Now use that $1=1-x+x$.